# Sending bulk data over SOAP API

Tags: webservices, schedulebatch

I have a requirement where I have to send approx. 30K records from Salesforce each day (once a day job) over SOAP API. The destination's webservice runs in 3 phases: Send, Poll and Retrieve. I have 3 functions to accommodate the 3 phases. The next phase function should be called couple of minutes after completion of the previous phase.

I am thinking of using Batchable interface in Salesforce. Is it a right approach?

If so can I include multiple functions(Send, Poll, Retrieve) in the Bactchable class? Currently all the three functions reside in a Global Schedulable classes.

How many rows of records will be executed in a single batch? Can I change that limit?

If there are multiple batch will I be running out of webservice callout limit?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using schedulable class which divides the data into groups of 2K records and scheduling the http callout for each group.